# Using lookup data.table inside another data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` containing some values to look up and another `data.table` which should use some values of the lookup table for a computation. Unfortunately, both `data.table`s have the same column name I need to use.

Simplified example:

```
dt <- data.table(id=1:5, x1=101:105, key="id")
dt

   id  x1
1:  1 101
2:  2 102
3:  3 103
4:  4 104
5:  5 105

lookup <- data.table(id=c(2,3,5), x2=c(102,103,105), key="id")
lookup

   id  x2
1:  2 102
2:  3 103
3:  5 105
```

Note, that the least significant digit of `x1` and `x2` is the same as `id` to relate it easily in the examples.

Now, I want to do something similar to

```
dt[id <= 3, .(id, x1, x2=lookup[.(??id??), x2])]
```

to achieve

```
   id  x1  x2
1:  1 101  NA
2:  2 102 102
3:  3 103 103
```

But I cannot figure out what to insert as `??id??`. So far I've tried:

- `id`: Does not work because it's interpreted as `lookup`'s `id` key, thus there is no relation between the `id`s leading to a broken result.
- `dt$id`: Does not work, because it is interpreted as the whole vector `dt[, id]` without the filter `id <= 3`. Thus I receive some warnings about non-matching numbers of items and a broken result.
- `dt[.I]$id` or `dt$id[.I]`: Works, but does not look "right", because it's not the `id` used in `dt`'s `j` argument itself but a similar copy.
- I also experimented with `get` and `eval` without success.

I know I can achieve my expected result by a join operation:

```
lookup[dt[id <= 3], on="id"]
```

And even do further computations in the `j` argument on `dt`'s and `lookup`'s columns.

But I still would prefer the expression above with the correct replacement for `??id??`, because I consider it more expressive for my purpose. I assume I need to know the right environment to insert there.

Is this possible and how?

Comment: I don't understand why `lookup[dt[id <= 3], on="id"]` is not acceptable.

Comment: `lookup[dt[id <= 3], on="id"]` looks much cleaner and robust to me. Any solution which includes manually taking all the column seems like bad idea to me.

Comment: I consider ``dt[id <= 3, .(id, x1, x2=lookup[.(??id??), x2])]`` more expressive, because I can immediately see that ``x2`` values of ``lookup`` are applied to do a computation with ``dt`` elements. In ``lookup[dt[id <= 3], on="id"]`` this is not so obvious for me, partly because ``dt`` is inside ``lookup``.  Maybe this also results from me being new to R but an otherwise experienced programmer.

Comment: For loops are also very expressive. That doesn't make using them in R a good idea (on average). Perhaps `lookup[dt[id <= 3], on = 'id', .(id, x1 = i.x1, x2 = x.x2)]` would satisfy the expressiveness of your soul since you can explicitly see where each variable is coming from.

Comment: @eddi: Thanks, that would at least be an improvement of the join solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the filter again like this to achieve what you're trying to.

```
dt[id <= 3, .(id, x1, x2=lookup[.(dt[id<=3]$id), x2])]
```

Comment: Thanks and +1 for your suggestion. Unfortunately, it is not quite what I'm looking for, because it repeats the condition ``id<=3`` leading to potential errors when accidentally changing only one of them. I'm more looking for an environment reference to access the ``id`` of ``dt`` instead of ``lookup``.